How to Centralize HTTP Response Handling and Navigation in a Kotlin MVVM Android App with Multiple Fragments?
Let's say we have an Android-Kotlin single activity application where each screen is a Fragment implemented using the MVVM pattern. The application has the following layers:

View: Fragments
ViewModel: Sits between the Fragments (View) and the Repositories from the Model layer.
Model: Consists of data sources and repositories that interact with data sources.

In the Repository layer, I have an apiCall function like this:
inline fun <T> apiCall(crossinline apiCall: suspend () -> Response<T>) = flow {
    emit(State.Progress(0))
    val response = apiCall()
    val responseBody = response.body()
    if (response.isSuccessful && responseBody != null)
        emit(State.Success(responseBody))
    else
        emit(State.Error(HttpException(response)))
}.catch {
    emit(State.Error(it))
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

this function is used this way in repositories for example:
fun checkOtpCode(phoneNumber: String, code: String) =
    apiCall { remoteDataSource.checkOtp(phoneNumber,code) }

In apiCall function, I need to inform the View layer that if the response code is in the 5xx range, the app should navigate to a server error fragment, or if it's a 401 or 403 status code, it should navigate to the login fragment—without repeating navigation and status code checking logic in all fragments, while still adhering to the MVVM architectural pattern and don't making code so ugly.
Someone suggested having a global SharedFlow and collecting it in the MainActivity. For example, if the status code is in the 5xx range, the globalFlow.emit(NavDest.ServerError) would be called, and global navigation would be handled in the MainActivity.
But I'm not very comfortable with this solution:
object SharedEventBus {
    private val _globalEvent = MutableSharedFlow<Event>()
    val globalEvent: SharedFlow<Event> = _globalEvent

    suspend fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
        _globalEvent.emit(event)
    }

    sealed class Event {
        object NavigateToLogin : Event()
        object NavigateToServerError : Event()
    }
}


"I have an apiCall function like this" -- generally, we use a Flow for sending back multiple results. You have a single result. For that, a simpler suspend fun should suffice. "I need to inform the View layer that if the response code is in the 5xx range, the app should navigate to a server error fragment, or if it's a 401 or 403 status code, it should navigate to the login fragment" -- no, you need to tell the view layer that you got a severe server error (5xx) or an authentication error (401/403). It is up to the view layer to decide what to do for those states.

"without repeating navigation and status code checking logic in all fragments" -- the status code checking logic would be in your repository. For example, based on your sample API call, you would have different State sub-types for server errors and authentication failures. In terms of navigation, put some utility code in a base fragment class that the other fragments extend. However, many complex apps will not be able to use some sort of "one size fits all" handling of navigation for authentication.

I have made some modifications to your apiCall function. It now allows you to handle different exceptions explicitly, enabling you to configure your state based on the type of exception:
inline fun <T> apiCall(crossinline apiCall: suspend () -> Response<T>) = flow {
    emit(State.Progress(0))
    val response = apiCall()
    val responseBody = response.body()
    when (response.status.value) {
        in 200..299 -> emit(State.Success(responseBody))
        401 -> throw emit(State.Error(UnauthorizedException()))
        in 400..499 -> throw emit(State.Error(BadRequestException()))
        in 500..599 -> throw emit(State.Error(ServerErrorException()))
        else -> throw emit(State.Error(UnknownNetworkException()))
    }
}.catch {
    emit(State.Error(it))
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

Custom Exceptions
To make this work, you'll need to define your custom exceptions:
open class NetworkException(message: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null) :
    Exception(message, cause)

class UnauthorizedException(cause: Throwable? = null) :
    NetworkException(message = "Unauthorized", cause = cause)

class ServerErrorException : NetworkException(message = "Server error")

class BadRequestException : NetworkException(message = "Bad request")

class DataConversionException(cause: Throwable? = null) :
    NetworkException(message = "Data conversion error", cause = cause)

class UnknownNetworkException(cause: Throwable? = null) :
    NetworkException(message = "Unknown network error $cause", cause = cause)

Handling Unauthorized Exceptions in ViewModel
For example, if you encounter an UnauthorizedException, you can update your state like this:
isUnauthorized = e is UnauthorizedException

Navigation on Unauthorized
Depending on the navigation library you're using, you can handle the navigation as follows:
@Composable
fun CheckIfUnauthorized(isUnauthorized: Boolean) {
    LaunchedEffect(isUnauthorized) {
        if (isUnauthorized) {
            // Navigate to the login screen
        }
    }
}

Usage in a Composable
You can call this function whenever you collect your state from your ViewModel:
val viewModel = viewModel<ExampleViewModel>()
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

CheckIfUnauthorized(state.isUnauthorized)


Suggestion
While this approach works, I recommend considering replacing the Flow with a Result<> type for simplicity and better readability. Hope this helps!
